# Is there a law or concept related to unchanging average?

Tags: mean, survey, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

I have a survey comprising 30 questions with 50k respondents where respondents mark each answer on a 5 point scale. An average of all the questions for all the respondents is metric we track monthly. We compare the month on month average of all the questions.

Lately, we have felt that the average is unchanging. Though the sub themes scores do vary, the overall mean/average is more or less constant. A sub theme is collection of 4-5 similar questions. I would like to investigate it further on reasons on why it doesn't seem to budge.

I have come across

1. The law of large numbers
2. Central limit theorem
3. Concepts related to stock index of multiple stocks which I do not fully understand

But I feel that the above concepts cannot explain this fully. I suspect that we have reached a potential maximum (Current average of 4) for the average for a survey, although it is not close to the theoretical maximum (Average of 5). Is there a way to test this or do you have any other possible explanations for it not changing?

Comment: Are the 50k respondents different or same each month?

Comment: Same. But does it matter?

Comment: Not sure. Reason I asked is that I how confidently can you say that average would change if there were lesser number of (same) participants? Could it not be that whatever this survey is about the respondants are more or less giving same ratings now (especially because they are same set of respondants).

Comment: We keep making numerous interventions trying to basically increase satisfaction. Since it's unchanging, we thought of 3 possible explanations:
1. Interventions aren't working?
2. We have reached the maximum possible average that is practically possible - something to do with surveys?

3. Moving the average of 50k respondents for 30 different questions is impossible?

Testing point 1 is simple. But how do I go about proving or disproving the other two?